# page 'analysis_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

this is my error
CS1061: 'analysis_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'analysis_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

my code in aspx file:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Happy" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Height="40px" Width="100px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

i have 3 buttons like this.

my codebehind that is .cs file is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

i have seen some related questions but in most questions they are missing  something so they got the error but for me i don,t know why i am getting this error .

someone can show me the right direction.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Are you using `MasterPage`? Check the name and namespace of the `CodeFile` specified in the `<%@ Page`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue , i changed all Button naming to new button say button1 to button2 and build and ran it worked. it may be looking at the same button 1 in another page ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete that button. Clean and rebuild the code. Add a new button again. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the button is added to the designer file of the aspx. This problem happens when the designer file is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**